# Delegate some evaluation to the visitor of the imported grammar in ANTLR 4

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am currently trying to implement multiple different grammars which share some concepts.

Let's say they look like this - this has nothing to do with my actual grammar:

grammar pathBase;

```
extension
  : 'txt'                     #txtExt
  | 'tar'                     #tarExt
  | 'gz'                      #gzExt
  | extension '.' extension   #compositeExt
  ;
```

And say there are some os specific path grammars.
One for windows:

```
grammar win;
import base;

path: DRIVE ('\' NAME)+ ('.' extension)?;
```

And one for linux:

```
grammar linux;
import base;

path: ('/' NAME)+ ('.' extension)?;
```

Now I have two different grammars which have two different parsers (WinParser and LinuxParser) with completely seperate contexts for `extension`. Since I want to avoid code repetition I now create a `PathBaseBaseVisitor` which reacts to all the rules defined in this base grammar:

`visitTxtExt`, `visitTarExt`, `visitGzExt`, `visitCompositeExt`

They all only accept `PathBaseParser.*Context` objects.

This means when I implement my Visitors for `win` and `linux` which only provide `WinParser.*Context` and `LinuxParser.*Context` (which are not subclasses of the contexts in `PathBaseParser`), I can't seem to be able to use the `PathBaseBaseVisitor` I just implemented by simply calling `visit()` on the given ExtensionContext.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

The only thing I seem to come up with is calling `getText()` on the context and reparsing it with the `PathBaseParser` but that seems dirty to me.

Comment: I'm talking about java of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle multiple syntax variants, as you appear to be trying to do, your target should be to construct a single grammar that imports the subset of rules that defines a variant.  That is, in your example, 'base' should be your primary grammar and the imported grammar should contain the 'path' rule. No other practical way to avoid the inheritance issues you encountered.

To be certain, if the difference in variants is large or likely to become large (eg Python 2 -> Python 3), the effort to maintain interdependent grammars will quickly outweigh the perceived benefits.  Conversely, if small, you can use predicates to handle the differences

```
path : { os().isWindows() }? DRIVE ('\' NAME)+ ('.' extension)?
     | { os().isLinux() }?   DRIVE ('/' NAME)+ ('.' extension)?
     | ...
     ;
```

Comment: Sadly this is not possible in my usecase since modules should be able to extend the grammar after the base grammar has been compiled.
But i guess you are right with the conclusion that there is no other way.
I think, I will end up with reparsing the "extension" equivalent in my grammar :)